# Can anyone explain this method signature? What does <K> and K... represent?

Tags: java

Howdy, I am trying to understand this method signature:

```
  public <K> Map<K, String> getMulti(Serializer<K> keySerializer, K... keys)
```

For the following code block:

```
public <K> Map<K, String> getMulti(Serializer<K> keySerializer, K... keys) {
    MultigetSliceQuery<K, String, String> q = createMultigetSliceQuery(keyspace, keySerializer, serializer, serializer);
    q.setColumnFamily(CF_NAME);
    q.setKeys(keys);
    q.setColumnNames(COLUMN_NAME);

    QueryResult<Rows<K, String, String>> r = q.execute();
    Rows<K, String, String> rows = r.get();
    Map<K, String> ret = new HashMap<K, String>(keys.length);
    for (K k : keys) {
        HColumn<String, String> c = rows.getByKey(k).getColumnSlice().getColumnByName(COLUMN_NAME);
        if (c != null && c.getValue() != null) {
            ret.put(k, c.getValue());
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I am not sure what `<K>` in the method declaration represents, or what `K...` is suppose to mean. Can anyone shed some light on these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `K` is the [type parameter of this method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html). It can be anything you want. E.g. `Integer`. In that case you need to *visually* (in your mind) substitute all `K`'s in the method signature with `Integer` to understand what it's taking and returning. With `Integer` as `K`, the method will then behave as follows:

```
public Map<Integer, String> getMulti(Serializer<Integer> keySerializer, Integer... keys)
```

The `...` in turn is the [varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) syntax. It allows you to pass zero-more arguments of or an array of the given type into the method. E.g.

```
getMulti(serializer);
getMulti(serializer, k1);
getMulti(serializer, k1, k2, k3);
```

Answer (score 3):

`K` is a generic type. `<K>` just declares that the declaration will talk about some generic type called `K`. Here the coder can declare restrictions on `K` like `<K extends List>`, or not.

Then `K` is simply used as a placeholder, a generic type. When you call this with a `Serializer<String>` for example, then imagine that the method will be invoked as if `K` were replaced with the type `String` throughout the method.

That's all that's going on as regards `K`.

If you want an interpretation of the method signature in English: it takes a `Serializer` that operates on `K`s, and zero or more `K`s. It returns a mapping from `K`s to `String`s.

Comment: If I am writing a method that needs a key to passed as a parameter, and I know for sure what class that key will be a reference of, do I need to use `K` as a placeholder? E.g. `private boolean capReached(K key)` vs. `private boolean capReached(Integer key)`. In my case Im using this method to limit the size of a LinkedHashMap.

Answer (score 0):

K simply denotes the presence of generics -- this method operates on a generic class K. It takes a serializer operating on the generic class K and a variable array of arguments of type K and it returns a map which maps instances of K to Strings.

Answer (score 0):

`K` here stands for 'key'.

Generic map declaration usually have a signature `Map<K,V>`, where `K` stands for arbitrary key type and `V` for arbitrary value type.

In your case value type is bounded to `String`.